# Flow number condition returning false

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, flow, power-automate, microsoft-flow

Flow condition is returning False, even though the condition is actually true.

Condition: if *Total score* is greater than or equal *7*.

[image: flow image]

here is a full flow picture[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the data type of "Total score" column in SharePoint list/library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "Total score" column is of type "Number" in SharePoint list/library, use condition like below:

[image]

Enter **7** directly in the textbox at right side.

---

**Update from comments**:

Try converting both sides of conditions to same format.

For example: I am converting both sides to `float` type like:

```
float(triggerOutputs()?['body/CalcMin'])  is greater than or equal to  float('7')
```

[image]

Comment: Ganesh, 
Still returning False.
total score is a calculated column with number formatting.

Comment: I have added another picture to the posts. hope this helps :(

Comment: Ganesh! Thanks a million for your support always! I made some tastings and I came to realise that the reason why condition was not working correctly was due to calculated column. Created a new number column and updated value from my total score. Used your original advised and flow is working ok and it is stable :)